# "ecmascript-6" and "es6" Is there a reason for two two different tags for EcmaScript 6?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

There are currently 174 questions tagged with [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) and 40 questions tagged with [es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6). Is there a difference between the two tags I am not aware? For me it looks reasonable to retag all questions with [es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6) to [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6).

Comment: Someone with enough rep in the tags probably should propose one as a synonym of the other. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/es6/synonyms  I don't have the rep in either tag to be able to do it, and looks like you don't either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been dealt with by animuson, and done the right way. ecmasccript-6 is now the main tag for any es6 and ecmascript-6 tagged question.