# Proxy: [es6-] or [javascript-]?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

As far as I know, both [es6-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6-proxy) and [javascript-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-proxy) are about the built-in [`Proxy` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). The former is much more popular (239 vs. 35 questions) and informative (wiki created in 2015 vs. never).

We already have plenty of `es6-` tags: [es6-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6-class), [es6-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6-promise), [es6-generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6-generator), etc. `Proxy` itself is also a ES6+ feature. On the other hand, tags whose name starts with `javascript-`are typically about generic features: [javascript-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-date), [javascript-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-event) (or [javascript-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-events)?), [javascript-decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-decorators), etc.

That said, [javascript-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-proxy) is probably a yet-to-be-synonymized synonym of [es6-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6-proxy).

Could a moderator merge them, please?

---

Edit: My intention wasn't to make this a generic discussion to rename all `es6-` to `javascript-`, but if we're going to rename every one of those, I'm in favor of `javascript-`, having been convinced by @VLAZ.

Comment: I would suggest to retag the few (35) questions with [[tag:javascript-proxy]] then rename the [[tag:es6-proxy]] tag.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Honestly, I do not see the reason to have the "es6-" prefix. The so-called "ES6 features" were only introduced with the 6th version of the ECMAScript specification in 2015. However, many have grown and evolved since then. The moniker "ES6" does not seem to fit.

We can take [es6-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6-class) as an example. Classes were introduced in ES6 but have also been extended later. ES13 (ECMAScript 2022) introduced private fields and static blocks. Would it make sense to still talk about the ES6 classes if anybody asks about static blocks? It is not an ES6 feature at that point. What about [es6-generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6-generator) - if somebody asks about async generators, how is that tag appropriate, given that it is an ES9/ECMAScript 2018 feature.

If you find my argument shaky, then answer this: if we *are* going to have ES6-* prefixes for features introduced in ES6 - why do we not have any equivalent ones? Do we have a tag [es5-array.prototype.map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es5-array.prototype.map) or just [array.prototype.map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array.prototype.map)? How about [es5-strict-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es5-strict-mode) vs [strict-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strict-mode)? Why is it that ES6 is segregated when, for all intents and purposes, adding classes is the exact same enhancement to the language as adding strict mode - it is a new permanent feature for all the years to come.

It makes a lot more sense to drop the ES6. At this point in time, it has been 8 years since ES6 has been adopted as a standard. And has been superseded by 8 other versions of the spec, all of them building on top of everything before. The whole [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) tag is *very* often misapplied on questions that either have nothing to do with ES6 itself or *at best* are just asking for "short syntax" (because the question asker expected using an arrow function or a `for..of` loop or other more recent options to be the answer) even if the actual solution comes from ES7, ES8, ES9, etc.

Comment: I won't argue about whether `es6-` is appropriate or not. We have [some](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278668) [discussions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297774) about that already. The main problem here is to choose between `es6-` and `javascript-`, and I'm in favor of the former. If there was a third, better, version, I would choose that instead.

Comment: "*I won't argue about whether es6- is appropriate or not*" Yet, it's something pertinent if you're asking to use "es6-\*". For it if is *not* appropriate, then we shouldn't be adopting it.

Comment: Also, the discussion isn't really about ES6 being appropriate. But just how to call the main tag.

Comment: Most of the [es6-*] tags also have a language agnostic tag which can be used instead in combination with [javascript]. This is particularly true for [es6-generator], where the language-agnostic [[tag:generator]] not only exists, but [javascript] is the second most common tag on [generator] questions (the most common one being [python]). Even [[tag:class]] has 5551 questions also tagged [javascript] making [javascript] the 8th most common tag on [class] questions.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I agree, I'd also be in favour of a tag combination. Similar to how [[tag:arrays]] is used.

Comment: @DonaldDuck The problem with these language-agnostic tags are is that they are sometimes too generic. [[tag:generator]] might be used for generator functions, but there's also code generators, parser generators, level generators etc. As for [[tag:class]], there are many questions asking about the abstract OOP concept (which was used since ES1 with constructors and prototype methods) whereas [[tag:es6-class]] refers to specifically the `class` syntax introduced with ES6. And [[tag:proxy]] has the proxy pattern, http proxies, SOCKS proxies, object proxies, and surely more.

Answer (score 19):

To add to VLAZ's answer:

From the point of view of someone asking a question: Does this person know in what proposal a feature was introduced? I would guess the answer is no. Do we want people to have to iterate through who knows how many es### prefixes just to find a suitable tag? Probably not either.

If we want to have a language agnostic version, lets use [javascript-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-proxy) instead of [es6-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6-proxy). That version can be found by your run-of-the-mill question asker without requiring an edit by someone familiar with the tag landscape and without guessing.

Comment: The run-of-the-mill asker is going to use [tag:proxy], ignoring the tag wiki cautioning them not to.

Comment: Very true. I get the idea that "ES6" is often used to indicate a level of Javascript that "probably won't work on IE". Its past it's due date, IMO.

Comment: @user3840170 also very true, these tag renames are more for people editing the tags to make it easier to pick the right ones. They deserve our support as well. More so, I would say.